# How to Make a Struct Version of the NSCountedSet Class?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, class, struct

I am developing an app in which I need to take two arrays, both holding the same custom data type, MenuItem.

I need to compare them and find the common elements of both arrays.
I compare the two arrays by converting them both to sets and then using the compare function of the set struct.

However, I then need to convert the array of common elements to a Counted Set so that I can find how many of each element exist in the group of common elements.

The problem I am having is with converting the the array of common elements to a Counted Set. In Swift, there is an `NSCountedSet` class but no `CountedSet` struct like there are for most built-in swift Data Types:

```
    let groups = Array(self.menu.keys) 
    //menu and cart are dictionaries the structure [MenuGroup: [MenuItem]]
    let cartGroups = Array(self.cart.keys)
    let group = groups[indexPath.section]

    if cartGroups.contains(group) {

        let items = menu[group] as [MenuItem]!
        let cartItems = cart[group]

        let itemsSet = Set<MenuItem>(items!)
        let cartItemsSet = Set<MenuItem>(cartItems!)

        let similarSet = itemsSet.intersection(cartItemsSet)
        let similarArray = NSMutableArray(Array(similarSet))
        let similarCounterSet = NSCountedSet(array: similarArray)

    }
```

**I want to create a struct based off the `NSCountedSet` class so that I can convert the array of common elements to a counted set.**

The `if` statement is for something else, it does not pertain to this question.

Any thoughts on how to do this? If anybody has a different approach to this problem feel free to mention that too.

Thanks,
Simon

Comment: There are various CountedSet implementation available, e.g. https://github.com/0x7fffffff/CountedSet.

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [Martin R](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1187415/martin-r) I Found An Example of How to do This:

> There are various CountedSet implementation available, e.g. https://github.com/0x7fffffff/CountedSet.